# Parsing PPM images in Haskell

Tags: parsing, haskell, ppm

I'm starting to learn Haskell and wish to parse a PPM image for execrsice. The structure of the PPM format is rather simple, but it is tricky. It's described [here](http://paulbourke.net/dataformats/ppm/). First of all, I defined a type for a PPM Image:

```
data Pixel = Pixel { red :: Int, green :: Int, blue :: Int} deriving(Show)
data BitmapFormat = TextualBitmap | BinaryBitmap deriving(Show)
data Header = Header { format :: BitmapFormat
                     , width :: Int
                     , height :: Int
                     , colorDepth :: Int} deriving(Show)
data PPM = PPM { header :: Header
               , bitmap :: [Pixel]
               }
```

`bitmap` should contain the entire image. This is where the first challange comes - the part that contains the actual image data in PPM can be either textual or binary (described in the header).
For textual bitmaps I wrote the following function:

```
parseTextualBitmap :: String -> [Pixel]
parseTextualBitmap = map textualPixel . chunksOf 3 . wordsBy isSpace
                     where textualPixel (r:g:b:[]) = Pixel (read r) (read g) (read b)
```

I'm not sure what to do with binary bitmaps, though. Using `read` converts a string representation of numbers to numbers. I want to convert "\x01" to 1 of type Int.

The second challange is parsing the header. I wrote the following function:

```
parseHeader :: String -> Header
parseHeader = constructHeader . wordsBy isSpace . filterComments
              where
                filterComments = unlines . map (takeWhile (/= '#')) . lines
                formatFromText s
                  | s == "P6" = BinaryBitmap
                  | s == "P3" = TextualBitmap
                constructHeader (format:width:height:colorDepth:_) =
                  Header (formatFromText format) (read width) (read height) (read colorDepth)
```

Which works pretty well. Now I should write the module exported function (let's call it `parsePPM`) which gets the entire file content (`String`) and then return `PPM`. The function should call `parseHeader`, deterime the bitmap format, call the apropriate `parse(Textual|Binary)Bitmap` and then construct a PPM with the result. Once parseHeader returns I should start decoding the bitmap from the point that parseHeader stopped in. However, I cannot know in which point of the string parseHeader stopped. The only solution I could think of is that instead of `Header`, parseHeader will return `(Header,String)`, when the second element of the tuple is the remainder retrieved by constructHeader (which currently named as _). But I'm not really sure it's the "Haskell Way" of doing things.

To sum up my questions:
1. How do I decode the binary format into a list of `Pixel`
2. How can I know in which point the header ends

Since I'm learning Haskell by myself I have no one to actually review my code, so in addition to answering my questions I will appriciate any comment about the way I code (coding style, bugs, alternative way to do things, etc...).

Comment: Not enough time for a full answer, but you ought to look at [Data.Binary.Get](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/binary-0.7.1.0/docs/Data-Binary-Get.html) and [Data.ByteString.Lazy](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/bytestring-0.10.4.0/docs/Data-ByteString-Lazy.html).

Comment: Returning the unparsed remainder is most definitely "the Haskell way." Just have a look at how the `Read` typeclass is implemented in terms of the `ReadS` typeclass.

Comment: @JonPurdy - If I understand correctly I cannot mix `String` with `ByteString`, so if I wish to use `unpack` I have to access the file using ByteString's `readFile`. Wouldn't that hurt my ability to treat the header as text?

Comment: I think implicit in the PPM spec is the assumption that a PPM file is a file of ASCII characters / octets - ie. bytes. I doubt you'll ever see a UTF-16 encoded PPM file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets start with question 2 because it is easier to answer. Your approach is correct: as you parse things, you remove those characters from the input string, and return a tuple containing the result of the parse, and the remaining string. However, thereis no reason to write all this from scratch (except perhaps as an academic exercise) - there are plenty of parsers which will take care of this issue for you. The one I will use is [`Parsec`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec-3.0.0). If you are new to monadic parsing you should first read [the section on `Parsec` in RWH.](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/using-parsec.html)

As for question 1, if you use `ByteString` instead of `String`, then parsing single bytes is easy since single bytes are the atomic elements of `ByteString`s!

There is also the issue of the `Char`/`ByteString` interface. With `Parsec`, this is a non-issue since you can treat a `ByteString` as a sequence of `Byte` or `Char` - we will see this later.

I decided to just write the full parser - this is a very simple language so with all the primitives defined for you in the `Parsec` library, it is very easy and very concise.

The file header:

```
import Text.Parsec.Combinator
import Text.Parsec.Char
import Text.Parsec.ByteString
import Text.Parsec 
import Text.Parsec.Pos

import Data.ByteString (ByteString, pack)
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as C8

import Control.Monad (replicateM)
import Data.Monoid
```

First, we write the 'primitive' parsers - that is, parsing bytes, parsing textual numbers, and parsing whitespace (which the PPM format uses as a seperator):

```
parseIntegral :: (Read a, Integral a) => Parser a
parseIntegral = fmap read (many1 digit)
```

`digit` parses a single digit - you'll notice that many function names explain what the parser does - and `many1` will apply the given parser 1 or more times. Then we read the resulting string to return an actual number (as opposed to a string). In this case, the input `ByteString` is being treated as text.

```
parseByte :: Integral a => Parser a
parseByte = fmap (fromIntegral . fromEnum) $ tokenPrim show (\pos tok _ -> updatePosChar pos tok) Just
```

For this parser, we parse a single `Char` - which is really just a byte. It is just returned as a `Char`. We could safely make the return type `Parser Word8` because the universe of values that can be returned is `[0..255]`

```
whitespace1 :: Parser ()
whitespace1 = many1 (oneOf "\n ") >> return ()
```

`oneOf` takes a list of `Char` and parses any one of the characters in the order given - again, the `ByteString` is being treated as `Text`.

Now we can write the parser for the header.

```
parseHeader :: Parser Header 
parseHeader = do
  f <- choice $ map try $ 
         [string "P3" >> return TextualBitmap
         ,string "P6" >> return BinaryBitmap]
  w <- whitespace1 >> parseIntegral
  h <- whitespace1 >> parseIntegral
  d <- whitespace1 >> parseIntegral
  return $ Header f w h d
```

A few notes. `choice` takes a list of parsers and tries them in order. `try p` takes the parser p, and 'remembers' the state before `p` starts parsing. If p succeeds, then `try p == p`. If p fails, then the state before p started is restored and you pretend you never tried `p`. This is necessary due to how `choice` behaves.

For the pixels, we have two choices as of now:

```
parseTextual :: Header -> Parser [Pixel]
parseTextual h = do
  xs <- replicateM (3 * width h * height h) (whitespace1 >> parseIntegral)
  return $ map (\[a,b,c] -> Pixel a b c) $ chunksOf 3 xs
```

We could use `many1 (whitespace 1 >> parseIntegral)` - but this wouldn't enforce the fact that we know what the length should be. Then, converting the list of numbers to a list of pixels is trivial.

For binary data:

```
parseBinary :: Header -> Parser [Pixel]
parseBinary h = do
  whitespace1
  xs <- replicateM (3 * width h * height h) parseByte
  return $ map (\[a,b,c] -> Pixel a b c) $ chunksOf 3 xs
```

Note how the two are almost identical. You could probably generalize this function (it would be especially useful if you decided to parse the other types of pixel data - monochrome and greyscale).

Now to bring it all together:

```
parsePPM :: Parser PPM
parsePPM = do
  h <- parseHeader
  fmap (PPM h) $ 
       case format h of
         TextualBitmap -> parseTextual h
         BinaryBitmap  -> parseBinary  h
```

This should be self-explanatory. Parse the header, then parse the body based on the format. Here are some examples to try it on. They are the ones from the specification page.

```
example0 :: ByteString
example0 = C8.pack $ unlines 
  ["P3"
  , "4 4"
  , "15"
  , " 0  0  0    0  0  0    0  0  0   15  0 15"
  , " 0  0  0    0 15  7    0  0  0    0  0  0"
  , " 0  0  0    0  0  0    0 15  7    0  0  0"
  , "15  0 15    0  0  0    0  0  0    0  0  0" ]

example1 :: ByteString
example1 = C8.pack ("P6 4 4 15 ") <> 
  pack [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 15, 0, 15, 0, 0, 0, 0, 15, 7, 
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 15, 7, 0, 0, 0, 15,
        0, 15, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ]
```

Several notes: this doesn't handle comments, which are part of the spec. The error messages are not very useful; you can use the [`<?>`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec-3.0.0/docs/Text-Parsec-Prim.html#v%3a-60--63--62-) function to create your own error messages. The spec also indicates 'The lines should not be longer than 70 characters.' - this is also not enforced.

edit:

Just because you see do-notation, doesn't necessarily mean that you are working with impure code. Some monads (like this parser) are still pure - they are just used for convenience. For example, you can write your parser with the type `parser :: String -> (a, String)`, or, what we have done here, is we use a new type: `data Parser a = Parser (String -> (a, String))` and have `parser :: Parser a`; we then write a monad instance for `Parser` to get the useful do-notation. To be clear, `Parsec` supports monadic parsing, but our parser is not monadic - or rather, uses the `Identity` monad, which is just `newtype Identity a = Identity { runIdentity :: a }`, and is only necessary because if we used `type Identity a = a` we would have 'overlapping instances' errors everywhere, which is not good.

```
>:i Parser
type Parser = Parsec ByteString ()
        -- Defined in `Text.Parsec.ByteString'
>:i Parsec
type Parsec s u = ParsecT s u Data.Functor.Identity.Identity
        -- Defined in `Text.Parsec.Prim'
```

So then, the type of `Parser` is really `ParsecT ByteString () Identity`. That is, the parser input is `ByteString`, the user state is `()` - which just means we aren't using the user state, and the monad in which we are parsing is `Identity`. `ParsecT` is itself just a newtype of:

```
forall b.
    State s u
    -> (a -> State s u -> ParseError -> m b)
    -> (ParseError -> m b)
    -> (a -> State s u -> ParseError -> m b)
    -> (ParseError -> m b)
    -> m b
```

All those functions in the middle are just used to pretty-print errors. If you are parsing 10's of thousands of characters and an error occurs, you won't be able to just look at it and see where that happened - but `Parsec` will tell you the line and column. If we specialize all the types to our `Parser`, and pretend that `Identity` is just `type Identity a = a`, then all the monads disappear and you can see that the parser is not impure. As you can see, `Parsec` is a lot more powerful than is required for this problem - I just used it due to familiarity, but if you were willing to write your own primitive functions like `many` and `digit`, then you could get away with using `newtype Parser a = Parser (ByteString -> (a, ByteString))`.

Comment: Thank you for the well described answer. I'm missing some basic knowlage needed to completly understand it so I will return to it after further reading. I have one question about it, though - I noticed that the parsing is done using do-notations, which (as I currently understand) makes these function impure. Isn't it a bad Haskell practice to write impure functions for non-IO things?

Comment: I edited my answer to address that - the tl;dr is that the parser that I've written is actually pure and that not all monads are impure.

Comment: In fact, all do notation is pure. The *execution* of IO actions in `main` by the runtime is the source of impurity, not the actual values of type `IO a` or their construction via do notation.